# SQL: how do you join to give you INVERSE rows?

Tags: sql, join

I have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT b.user_name FROM
(SELECT user_name FROM my_table_name
WHERE date='2013-07-11') a
JOIN
(SELECT user_name FROM my_table_name
WHERE date='2013-06-11') b
ON 
a.user_name != b.user_name
```

How do I do a JOIN that gives me the names in June, but NOT IN July?

Answer (score 2):

This is known as an anti join. The SQL Standard `EXCEPT` operator can be used if your RDBMS supports it.

```
SELECT user_name
FROM   my_table_name
WHERE  date = '2013-06-11'
EXCEPT
SELECT user_name
FROM   my_table_name
WHERE  date = '2013-07-11'
```

Other possibilities include `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN ... NULL` or you could use `GROUP BY` as below.

```
SELECT user_name
FROM   my_table_name
WHERE  date IN ('2013-06-11', '2013-07-11')
GROUP BY user_name
HAVING MAX(date) = '2013-06-11'
```

Comment: what if it's date >= '2013-07-11'   and    date >='2012-01-01' AND date <='2012-12-31'

Comment: The `EXCEPT` part remains the same but the individual `WHERE` clauses are adjusted so the top one includes the whole of june and the bottom one the whole of July. The `GROUP BY` one would have its `WHERE` clause adjusted to include the whole two months and the `HAVING` changed to `HAVING MAX(date) < '2013-07-01'`